# Android: How can I access a folder in a LAN through wifi?

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi, lan, getdirectories

I am trying to get the Ips connected to my Lan. I already do that. I want to know how to find a folder in those Ips. I have a shared folder in my PC and I want to have access to it through my App but I don´t know the specific IP because the router changes his IP on reset.

Comment: Search for "SMB" or "Windows Network Share", perhaps. There is also "NFS". Or "WebDAV". Or even accessing an HTTP "Folder". But you'll need 1) a server that "shares folders" and 2) a client that understands the protocol used to "share folders". The IP problem is addressed with the use of DNS (perhaps even "dynamic DNS") name resolution.